# How kotlin delegation is useful?

Tags: kotlin

I'm really confused about the kotlin delegation. Let me describe the regular polymorphism approach here which looks same like the kotlin delgation.

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}
class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { print(x) }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b : Base = BaseImpl(10)
    b.print() // prints 10
}
```

I can pass any implemented class of `Base` interface to `b` variable to call the method of specified class's object. Then what is the benefit of `kotlin`'s delegation? Which is described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html).

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}
class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { print(x) }
}
class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b // why extra line of code? 
                                   // if the above example works fine without it.
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b = BaseImpl(10)
    Derived(b).print() // prints 10
}
```

I know this is the simple scenario where the both codes are working fine. There should be a benefit of delegation that's why kotlin introduced it. What is the difference? and how kotlin delegation can be useful? Please give me a working example to compare with polymorphism approach.

Comment: I wonder if this is a question more about the merits of delegation itself than about how Kotlin implements it.

Comment: I asked it to know how the kotlin delegation useful? not how the delegation is useful. because I already know about the delegation purpose. But kotlin's implementation is confusing me.

Comment: The first block of code doesn't give the result equivalent to the second one. Try to implement `Derived` by hand, and you'll feel the difference.

Comment: Can you write the short code? Because I really don't know which example can differentiate them.

Comment: There are alot of blog posts out there addressing the topic "composition vs inheritance", e. g. https://codingdelight.com/2014/01/16/favor-composition-over-inheritance-part-1/ or https://www.thoughtworks.com/de/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also remember that you're not restricted to just one delegate. Kotlin's way of implementing delegation is similar to `traits` implementation in languages like Groovy. You can compose different functionality via delegates. Kotlin's way can also be considered more powerful because you can "plug in" different implementations too.

```
interface Marks {
  fun printMarks()
}

class StdMarks() : Marks {
  override fun printMarks() { println("printed marks") }
}

class CsvMarks() : Marks {
  override fun printMarks() { println("printed csv marks") }
}

interface Totals {
  fun printTotals()
}

class StdTotals : Totals {
  override fun printTotals() { println("calculated and printed totals") }
}

class CheatTotals : Totals {
  override fun printTotals() { println("calculated and printed higher totals") }
}

class Student(val studentId: Int, marks: Marks, totals: Totals) 
  : Marks by marks, Totals by totals

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
  val student = Student(1,StdMarks(), StdTotals())
  student.printMarks()
  student.printTotals()
  val cheater = Student(1,CsvMarks(), CheatTotals())
  cheater.printMarks()
  cheater.printTotals()
}
```

Output:

```
printed marks
calculated and printed totals
printed csv marks
calculated and printed higher totals
```

You can't do this with inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

It is extremely useful for creating decorators and for object composition.
Joshua Bloch in Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 16 'Favor Composition Over Inheritance' shows a good example: inheritance is easy-to-break, and decorators are not.

Inheritance:

```
class LoggingList<E> : ArrayList<E>() {

    override fun add(e: E): Boolean {
        println("added $e")
        return super.add(e)
    }

    override fun addAll(e: Collection<E>): Boolean {
        println("added all: $e")
        return super.addAll(e) // oops! Calls [add] internally.
    }

}
```

Delegation:

```
class LoggingList<E>(delegate: MutableList<E>) : MutableList<E> by delegate {

    override fun add(e: E): Boolean {
        println("added $e")
        return delegate.add(e)
    }

    override fun addAll(e: Collection<E>): Boolean {
        println("added all: $e")
        return delegate.addAll(e) // all OK
        // it calls [delegate]'s [add] internally, not ours
    }

}
```

Comment: I can still call the internally without ` : MutableList<E> by delegate` can you give me working example? So I can compare with the polymorphism approach.

Comment: I think you should elaborate much more on your example such that you can demonstrate how this proves to be "extremely useful" as you say. I'm afraid it is not so evident as you seem to suggest.

Comment: First of all, this is a working example, just copy&paste it into try.kotlinlang.org and try it out. Second: What Miha meant was, that `addAll` internally calls `add` on every new item. so in the inheritance-example you'll get "added all" and then "added xy" for every item, because we override `add()`. in the Delegation example you only get "added all", because the addAll doesnt call our `add`, but rather the `add` of MutableList

Answer (score 4):

It is useful because of the [Delegation Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) where most of the behavior can be the same as the target of the delegation (`b`) but you just want to override a subset of methods to act differently.

An example would be an `InputStream` implementation which delegates all work to another `InputStream` but overrides the `close()` method to not close the underlying stream. This could be implemented as:

```
class CloseGuardInputStream(private val base: InputStream)
    : InputStream by base {
    override fun close() {}
}
```

Comment: can you give tested example? so I can compare that example in the Interface polymorphism way. I know delegation is useful but how the kotlin's one?

Comment: Can you call the above code in the main method. So I can compare to interface polymorphism example?

Comment: This example actually does not work because InputStream is a class and not an interface. Delegation in Kotlin is only supported via interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the example :-

[image]

```
interface Mode{
val color:String
fun display()
 }

class DarkMode(override val color:String) : Mode{    
override fun display(){
    println("Dark Mode..."+color)
}
 }
class LightMode(override val color:String) : Mode {
override fun display() { 
    println("Light Mode..."+color) 
}
}

class MyCustomMode(val mode: Mode): Mode{
override val color:String = mode.color
override fun display() { 
    mode.display()
}
}
```

Now, the custom mode can reuse `display()` function of both modes `DarkMode` & `LightMode`

```
fun main() {
MyCustomMode(DarkMode("CUSTOM_DARK_GRAY")).display()
MyCustomMode(LightMode("CUSTOM_LIGHT_GRAY")).display()
}

 /* output:
 Dark Mode...CUSTOM_DARK_GRAY
 Light Mode...CUSTOM_LIGHT_GRAY
*/
```

Kotlin natively support delegation pattern.
Kotlin provides by keyword to specify the delegate object which our custom mode will be delegating to.
We can achieve the same result of the code above using by keyword.

```
class MyCustomMode(val mode: Mode): Mode by mode
fun main() {
MyCustomMode(DarkMode("CUSTOM_DARK_GRAY")).display()
MyCustomMode(LightMode("CUSTOM_LIGHT_GRAY")).display()
}

/* output:
Dark Mode...CUSTOM_DARK_GRAY
  Light Mode...CUSTOM_LIGHT_GRAY
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, delegates are special objects that allow one object to delegate certain operations or properties to another object. In other words, they allow one object to pass on the responsibility of performing certain tasks to another object.

Here's an example to better understand how delegates work in Kotlin:

```kotlin
// Create a delegate interface
interface Printer {
    fun print(message: String)
}

// Create a delegate class that implements the Printer interface
class ConsolePrinter : Printer {
    override fun print(message: String) {
        println(message)
    }
}

// Create a class that will use the delegate
class MessageProcessor(printer: Printer) : Printer by printer {
    fun processMessage(message: String) {
        print("Processing message: $message")
        // Other operations to process the message
    }
}

// Use the MessageProcessor class with the delegate
fun main() {
    val printer = ConsolePrinter()
    val processor = MessageProcessor(printer)
    processor.processMessage("Hello, World!")
}
```

In this example, we have an interface called `Printer`, which defines a `print` method, and a class called `ConsolePrinter` that implements this interface and prints the message to the console.

Then we have a class called `MessageProcessor`, which also implements the `Printer` interface using the delegate `by printer`. This means that all calls to the `print` method on the `MessageProcessor` object will be delegated to the `printer` object that was passed in the constructor.

In the `main` function, we create an instance of `ConsolePrinter`, and then create an instance of `MessageProcessor`, passing the `ConsolePrinter` as an argument to the constructor. We then call the `processMessage` method on the `MessageProcessor` object, which in turn calls the `print` method. This call to the `print` method will be delegated to the `ConsolePrinter` object, and we will see the message "Processing message: Hello, World!" printed to the console.

Thus, delegates allow us to split the responsibility between different objects and reuse functionality implemented in other objects.